# set custom header in HttpServletRequest in preHandle interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can i put a custom header in preHandle request interceptor method? I can see a function for setting header on response but not for request. Why is it so?

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,                                     
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
//function defination goes here 
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot. If you want, you need a filter and wrap your request. But wy do you want to add a header?

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to maintain my request context using thred local variable so i want to set a custom header 'x-request-id' so that i can filter my logs based on this id

Comment: ^ Also if this request spans more child requests(To different services) than i will have to provide same request context

Comment: That is a different request. The outgoing NOT the incoming request.